# How to read JsonResult object in c#

Tags: c#, jsonresult

I am trying to deserialize my jsonresult but I am getting an error message below:

> "Cannot convert from System.Web.Mvc.Result to string"

Here's my jsonresult:

```
[{"description":"BANANA","quantity":"12","productPrice":"40000","discount":"","isTaxable":true,"finalPrice":"9999","lineItemTotal":"999","orderId":8},{"description":"APPLES","quantity":"20","productPrice":"860000","discount":"","isTaxable":false,"finalPrice":"12000","lineItemTotal":"10000","orderId":8}]
```

Here's my controller method:

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateLineItems(JsonResult data)
        {


           ResultDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultDto>(data);
            //for (int i = 0; i < data.Data; i++)
            //{
            //    
            //}

            return data;
        }
```

Here's my ResultDto class:

```
public class ResultDto
    {

        public string description { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public string productPrice { get; set; }
        public string discount { get; set; }
        public bool isTaxable { get; set; }
        public string finalPrice { get; set; }
        public string lineItemTotal { get; set; }
        public int orderId { get; set; }
    }
```

The JsonResut contains two objects (i.e, banana and apple). So, I want to loop through the Data and get two ResultDtos . How do I achieve this?

This line gives me the error:  `ResultDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

I am sending the data like this from the view:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        data: JSON.stringify(lineitems)
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (reponse) {
                        alert("error : " + reponse);
                    }
                });
```

What's the best way to get this data ( which is an array of objects) in my controller? Once I get this data in my controller, I want to persist it in the db. So, I am not sure if JsonResult is the correct return type for my method.

Comment: try this `public JsonResult CreateLineItems(string data) { //your code here }`

Comment: isTaxable is bool in your json and orderid is int.

Comment: use `string` as parameter type for your `CreateLineItems` method instead of `JsonResult`

Comment: also your json is an List of object, so you have to deserialize as `List<ResultDto>` and `isTaxable` is `bool` and `orderId` is `int`

Answer (score 7):

You already have a JSon. The way to fix your issue right now is to stringify your JSONObject, and then deserialize it to the type you want.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult.Data);
ResultDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultDto>(json);
```

Comment: please see my edited question. Based on Tashi's answer, JsonResult shoul dbe used to return data back to view. So, if that is the case, then what parameter should I use to get the data from the view ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you managed to accept a `JsonResult` in your controller, but stop doing that. `JsonResult` is for returning data *to* the client, not to accept data *from* the client. Your controller should accept a `ResultDto[]`, which should deserialize automatically from your JSON by the MVC framework. Then, you can continue working on it.

Also, as others noted in comments, `isTaxable` is `bool` and `orderId` is `int`, so type your `ResultDto` properties correctly.

Comment: This is a great advice. I am going to tweak my code based on your suggestion and will let you know if I am successful.

Comment: It did not work. I am actually receiving something like this: ResltDto[0]. That's it. It's like a string. I am passing my lineitems like this form the ajax:   data: JSON.stringify(lineitems)

Comment: @bangbang from your code example it looks like you're sending an object in your `data` property for the `.ajax()` function. You should just send the result of `JSON.stringify(lineitems)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's because the JSONResult according to documentation : [jsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  is already formatted. You need to get into your data.Data object of jsonResult.

try replacing this:

```
ResultDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultDto>(data);
```

with this:

```
ResultDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultDto>(data.Data);
```

If this won't work try solution of Sakuto.

Answer (score 0):

Change `isTaxable` to `bool` firstly

```
public class ResultDto
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string productPrice { get; set; }
    public string discount { get; set; }
    public bool isTaxable { get; set; }
    public string finalPrice { get; set; }
    public string lineItemTotal { get; set; }
    public int orderId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, try to deserialize

```
var dtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResultDto>>(json);
foreach(var dto in dtos)
{
}
```